# How to run build on a docker container when jenkins is in a docker container

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have a jenkins single instance running in a docker container. The host is AWS `16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)` system. I want the jenkins run my build inside a docker container but since jenkins is already running inside a docker. I don't want a nested docker container running in the build. How can I make jenkins launch a docker container on the host instead of itself container?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for that is to mount this directory on jenkins container:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```